# GWT - How to handle multiple handlers for the same event

Tags: gwt, event-handling

I'm currently working on a GWT project. I have a common block shared between multiple pages. I have some action buttons on that common block and the pages have a handler for the event launched on the click of those action buttons.

The problem I'm facing is that when I click on one of those action buttons on Page A, the handler from Page B previsouly registered would be called too.

So the solution I thought of was to remove the handler from a page when we leave it so there would be only one page at once with a registered handler to the same action button event.

First, I register to the action button click events and save the HandlerRegistration object returned from the addHandler method:

```
HandlerRegistration actionButtonClickEventHandlerRegistration=eventBus.addHandler(CommonBlockActionButtonClickedEvent.TYPE, someHandler);
```

And then, on page change event, I call removeHandler from the previously saved HandlerRegistration object

```
eventBus.addHandler(PageChangeEvent.TYPE, new PageChangeEventHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onMainPageChange(PageChangeEvent event) {
        actionButtonClickEventHandlerRegistration.removeHandler();
    }
});
```

So I do that on every pages, except that when I lauch my app and go to two of those pages, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: redundant remove call
```

Do you guys have any idea of why I'm getting this error or another way to solve my issue ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set the handler to null after removing it and I would check if it is actually null before removing it.
Like this:

```
eventBus.addHandler(PageChangeEvent.TYPE, new PageChangeEventHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onMainPageChange(PageChangeEvent event) {
        if(actionButtonClickEventHandlerRegistration != null ) {
            actionButtonClickEventHandlerRegistration.removeHandler();
            actionButtonClickEventHandlerRegistration = null;
        }
    }
});
```

Nevertheless you seem to remove the handler at least twice and should check your program logic for that.

A good approach to do that is to set a breakpoint in the debugger (of your browser) on the line removing the handler. If you look at the call stack for every call to it, you should be able to spot the duplicate call and fix it.